# Word or expression for "someone using fake kindness to hide something or his true nature"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, personality

It's someone who tends to be a nice person but hides something or there is something off about him. Sometimes, you meet this kind of people and you know that his/her kindness hides a darker side.

I thought about *sly* or *shady* but they seem a bit too much, however I might be wrong. Is *deceitful* the correct term or is there a more specific one?

> **Example** :
>
> "I don't like the new boss, his kindness hides something"
>
> " I don't like the new boss, he is _____"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Dissembler" might fit your requirement. Though you might have to tweak the sentence a bit. 
"I don't like the new boss, he seems to be a dissembler."
This is because "seems to be" adds the connotations of having picked up such vibes from the person. "Is" implies more of a certain pronouncement on the character of the person.

Comment: Dissembler actually fits pretty well when you look at the definition. Its definition is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

As an adjective, I would like to use

hypocrite

hypocritical

insincere

double

double-faced

two-faced

double-tongued

On the other hand, as a noun , I would use

dissembler

prig

pharisee

double-dealer

Answer (score 1):

How about "two-faced"?

two-faced is an adjective you can use to someone who acts one way at a certain time/situation but acts differently at another time/situation.

Comment: If you want more rep, try [writing answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that will gain it.

Comment: Not quite. I think that a two-faced person is likely to betray you, but that is not the case. The person just wants to hide something.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the answer is right under our noses. At least in my case, I would refer to this person as ***fake***.

It requires some understanding of connotation, but in this case it lends itself quite easily:

> "I don't like the new boss, his kindness hides something. Does he not seem ***fake*** to you?"

Comment: How could I miss this simple word? Simple, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

The first word that I thought of was *smarmy:*

- [smarmy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smarmy) - *revealing or marked by a smug, ingratiating, or false earnestness*

Also *obsequious,* although this implies that the speaker is a [sycophant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sycophant):

- [obsequious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsequious) - *marked by or exhibiting a fawning attentiveness*

Comment: Not really. This person doesn't try to look superior or flatter anyone, he just wants to hide something.

Answer (score 0):

The entire thinking error goes kinda like this..."hides behind acts of kindness to commit atrocities." Now this is not exactly the way I saw it written which is why I'm asking.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

When the thing the person is hiding is an intent to do you harm, we have the specific phrase:

> wolf in sheep's clothing.